Most efficient way to conditionally sample my large df
I have a large DF (~35 million rows) and I  am trying to create a new df by randomly sampling two rows from each unique cluster ID (~1.8 million unique cluster IDs)-- one row must have a label 0 and one row must have a label 1 (sometimes there is only one label, so I must check first if both labels are present within the cluster). For reference, my dataset has 3 main cols: 'embeddings', 'cluster_ID', 'label'.
I'm finding that this process takes way more time than I anticipated (more than 15 hours), and I want to know if there is a way to optimize my code.
Please NOTE:
My original df only has 2 labels: 1 and 0. I should end up with more than 1.8 million rows. I would like to sample 2 rows for each cluster (one label 1 and other is label 0). Some clusters have a mixed bag of rows with both labels-- but some only have rows with label 1. If the former is the case: I want 2 rows from that cluster (one for each label)-- if the latter is the case: I only want one row from that cluster. Therefore: I should end up with between 1.8-3.6 million rows.
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create an empty list to store selected rows
selected_rows = []

# Iterate over unique cluster IDs
for cluster_id in result_df_30['cluster_ID'].unique():
    # Filter the DataFrame for the current cluster ID
    df_cluster = result_df_30[result_df_30['cluster_ID'] == cluster_id]
    
    # Filter rows with label 0 and 1
    df_label_0 = df_cluster[df_cluster['label'] == 0]
    df_label_1 = df_cluster[df_cluster['label'] == 1]
    
    # Sample rows if they exist
    if not df_label_0.empty:
        sample_label_0 = df_label_0.sample(n=1, random_state=42)
        selected_rows.append(sample_label_0)
    if not df_label_1.empty:
        sample_label_1 = df_label_1.sample(n=1, random_state=42)
        selected_rows.append(sample_label_1)

# Concatenate the selected rows into a single DataFrame
selected_rows_df = pd.concat(selected_rows)

selected_rows_df



What do you men by way more time than anticipated?

This is highly inefficient, you scan the entire data frame almost 2 million times just to get the groups, basically it's quadratic time. Use groupby instead

@juanpa.arrivillaga
Could you please write up an answer so that I can see your solution?

Updated requirements: sample 1 row from each cluster-label combination
sample = (
    df.sample(frac=1)
    .groupby(["cluster_ID", "label"], as_index=False)
    .first()
)

Original requirements: sample only from clusters with both 0 and 1 labels
This requires that your dataframe be sequentially indexed (0, 1, ..., 35m). That is super easy with df = df.reset_index(drop=True).
# Some test data
n = 35_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "embeddings": np.random.rand(n),
        "cluster_ID": np.random.randint(0, 1_800_000, n),
        "label": np.random.randint(0, 2, n),
    }
)

tmp = (
    # since you only care about rows with label 0 or 1
    df[df["label"].isin([0, 1])]  
    # shuffle the rows. This is where the randomness comes from
    .sample(frac=1) 
    # reset the index
    .reset_index()  
    # for each Cluster ID and label, get the number of the first row
    .pivot_table(index="cluster_ID", columns="label", values="index", aggfunc="first")
)

# Filter for clusters that have both 0 and 1, then get their row numbers
idx = tmp[tmp.notna().all(axis=1)].to_numpy("int").flatten()

# and your random sample
sample = df.iloc[idx]


My original df only has 2 labels: 1 and 0. I changed the code accordingly, but after running your code, I should end up with more than 1.8 million rows-- but I end up with exactly that amount. I need to sample 2 (or 1 if necessary) from each for each cluster. Some clusters have a mixed bag of rows with both labels-- some only have rows with label 1. If the former is the case: I want 2 rows from that cluster-- if the latter is the case: I only want one row from that cluster. Therefore: I should end up with between 1.8-3.6 million rows.

My sample.shape returns pretty much what you described. It has 3,599,554 rows to be exact. What does sample.shape return for you?

Using my real df, I got 31,386 rows

I think the problem is this line: # Filter for clusters that have both 0 and 1, then get their row numbers
idx = tmp[tmp.notna().all(axis=1)].to_numpy("int").flatten()
I don't want to only filter for clusters that have both 0 and 1. I want every cluster represented with up to 2 labels, if possible (if not, 1 label is OK).  How should I change that last line to be accurate?

Your original question gave me the impression that you only wanted clusters that have both the 0 and 1 labels. Updated the question even though you had marked it as answered
